# C# - Animated text in video

Tags: c#, animation, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I have a video and I want to add text on it on certain time and with certain animations.

I just need to know the method to do this or just the technology name (some tips would be great).

So far I found the FFMPEG library, it is very good for many video related stuff but not for animating text in video. I also tried many nuget libraries but could not get anything related.

Text animations I need includes fade, bounce,movement ,flip

ANY kind of help will really be appreciated.

Comment: Animating text = drawing on top of the frames, which is what you gotta do. I believe you can extract frames with FFMpeg.

Comment: So should i extract each frame frame from FFMpeg and draw on it? Can you please suggest me some tool for drawing text like that (squeezed/stretched for animation). and thanks @VisualVincent

Comment: You don't have to extract _every_ frame, I think you can choose a timespan. And what do you mean by _"squeezed/stretched"_? Text can be squeezed or stretched in many different ways.

Comment: The thing is that Stack Overflow is not really a forum for _"Please help me find this resource"_, so this question is altogether too broad and off-topic. You have to google for different solutions on how to draw text differently, but the standard way is to use the very optimized GDI+. Here's one article that I found: http://csharpdevelopertool.blogspot.se/2012/02/draw-text-stretched-to-fit-rectangle.html